# pandas to_sql, only update new rows to mysql db (primary key & duplicate)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am having problems updating pd to mysql db

```
for stock_code in cleaned:

    url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/chi/sorc/options/statistics_hv_iv_c.aspx?action=csv&type=3&ucode={0}'.format(stock_code)
    df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col='交易日', header=0, skiprows=2)
    df.index.names = ['Trade Date']
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
    df.insert(loc=0, column ='Stock Code', value=stock_code)
    df.columns = ['Stock Code', 'Implied IV (%)','HV10 (%)','HV30 (%)','HV60 (%)','HV90 (%)']
    df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='table', if_exists='append')

database_connection.close()
```

The url will provide data for nearest 3 months : ie. 2018-08-25 to 2018-11-25,
after today the url will give data 2018-08-26 to 2018-11-26, what I want is to save all the data in db without duplication.

I set 'Trade Date' & 'Stock Code' as primary key, but it yields error : 
(mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2018-11-23-00001' for key 'PRIMARY' [SQL

How can I skip the duplicate entry and only update new rows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: set 'Stock Code' + 'Trade Date'  as primary key (in order)

Comment: Sorry, can u elaborate a bit? Trade Date is index & Stock Code is a column